# $\overline{\text{ABCDA}}$ simply closed only if $\overline{\text{AB}}\cap\overline{\text{CD}}=\overline{\text{AD}}\cap\overline{\text{BC}}=\emptyset$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\textbf{A, B, C, D}$ be four points in an orderly incidence plane, while three of those points are noncollinear. Show that the closed line segment $\overline{\text{ABCDA}}$ is simply closed if and only if $\overline{\text{AB}}\cap\overline{\text{CD}}=\overline{\text{AD}}\cap\overline{\text{BC}}=\emptyset$.

Definitions:

orderly incidence plane: An incidence plane $(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{G})$ with the three digit relation $\cdot\mid\cdot\mid\cdot$ is an orderly incidence plane if the Axiom of Pasch holds true.
Axiom of Pasch: Let $\textbf{A, B, C}$ be three points that do not lie on a line and let $a$ be a line in the plane $\textbf{ABC}$ which does not meet any of the points $\textbf{A, B, C}$. If the line a passes through a point of the segment $\textbf{AB}$, it also passes through a point of the segment  $\textbf{AC}$, or through a point of segment  $\textbf{BC}$.

closed line segment: Let $n>1$ be an natural number and $\textbf{P}_1,...,\textbf{P}_n$ are points in the orderly incidence plane with $\textbf{P}_k\neq\textbf{P}_{k+1}$ for $1\leq k \leq n-1$.
A line segment or polygonal chain $\overline{\textbf{P}_1\cdot\cdot\cdot\textbf{P}_n}$ is the set defined by:
$\overline{\textbf{P}_1\cdot\cdot\cdot\textbf{P}_n}:=\underset{1\leq k \leq n-1}{\bigcup}$$\overline{\textbf{P}_k\textbf{P}_{k+1}}$

A line segment $\overline{\textbf{P}_1\cdot\cdot\cdot\textbf{P}_n}$ is called closed if $\textbf{P}_1=\textbf{P}_n$
It is simply closed if the following things hold true
(i) $\overline{\textbf{P}_1\cdot\cdot\cdot\textbf{P}_{k-1}}\cap\overline{\textbf{P}_{k-1}\textbf{P}_k}=\{\textbf{P}_{k-1}\}$ for $k\in \{3,...,n-1\}$
(ii)$\overline{\textbf{P}_1\cdot\cdot\cdot\textbf{P}_{n-1}}\cap\overline{\textbf{P}_{n-1}\textbf{P}_n}=\{\textbf{P}_{n-1},\textbf{P}_1\}$

An exercise from an old geometry exam where I unfortunately have no idea how to solve it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!